# Changing the detail Navigation Items in UISplitViewController iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, delegates, uisplitviewcontroller

I have 2 UINavigationControllers in a UISplitViewController. I want to change the detail controllers bar button items when the user goes into portrait mode on the iPad. I used to be able to change it by doing

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willHideViewController:    (UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc
{
barButtonItem.title = @"Title";

//put on left side
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;
```

}

But this method is deprecated in iOS 8.

I tried using

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willChangeToDisplayMode:(UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode)displayMode
 {
       if (displayMode == UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden) {
          self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title =   @"title";//self being the detail controller    
       }
 }
```

But that didn't work

I also looked at other questions and didnt find any explanatory answers. 
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out.

Theres a new property called displayMode and it is a new UIBarButtonItem

This is how to implement it

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willChangeToDisplayMode:    (UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode)displayMode
{
UINavigationItem *navItem = self.navigationItem;
navItem.leftBarButtonItem = [svc displayModeButtonItem];

}
- (UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode)targetDisplayModeForActionInSplitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc
{
if (svc.displayMode == UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden)
return UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible;

return UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden;
}
```